# can't login into customer account in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9

When I try to register as well as login into customer account, I am not redirected to my customer dashboard.

In registration customer details are registered clearly in database, but I am not redirected to my dashboard. After completing my customer registration it takes me into login page instead of my dashboard why???

I have already added:`getFormKey();`

In XAMPP everything works fine in my web server I face this problem.

Please help me.

Comment: Sounds like your session is broken somehow. Try to tweak your session and cookie settings in the admin or in the database in the `core_config_data` table.

Comment: thank you sir for your idea ... i tried everything still i face the same problem @7ochem

Comment: So the problem is that you're not redirected to dashboard after registration But can you access the dashboard by navigating there?

Comment: Try the Login Process in Mozilla Firefox Instead Of Google Chrome. I got the Same Problem In google Chrome But i logged in Mozilla Firefox Without Any issue. Just have a Try

Comment: please check .browswer cookie setting

Comment: Amit- OP says he has tried all session and cookie settings.

Answer (score 1):

**skype:** `dubeychandan996` I will help you. One more things while adding form key.

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
```

check whether you are pasting in same `login.phtml` that are used in frontend. sometimes in `xampp` also have cache issue.

For That `app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Session\Abstract\Varien.php`

```
/* to solve login issue */
  /*if (!$cookieParams['httponly']) {
  unset($cookieParams['httponly']);
  if (!$cookieParams['secure']) {
  unset($cookieParams['secure']);
  if (!$cookieParams['domain']) {
  unset($cookieParams['domain']);
  }
  }
  }

if (isset($cookieParams['domain'])) {
  $cookieParams['domain'] = $cookie->getDomain();*/ //I have commented these lines
```

or

- Open your Magento installation directory. Locate and open `index.php` file.
- Search for error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); code.
- Comment it out like that: `/*error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);*/`
- And use the following code instead:

  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  $_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'] = true;

  Uncomment it by removing the # sign, so it looks like that:

  **ini_set('display_errors', 1);**
- Save this file and upload to the server. Reload your website page to see errors.

==========alternative==================

## change localhost to 127.0.0.1

paste your error if you can see.